# Mock chain calls involves Stream in Java

Tags: java, junit, java-8, mockito, powermock

How can I mock chained calls with streams,. Also notice that it is calling each.getName() as an intermediate operation. 
I cannot create SomeCountobject so have to mock it also.

```
Set<String> obj = new HashSet<String>();
List<SomeCount> someGroups = Some_Mocked_Implementation();
obj = someGroups.stream().map(each -> each.getName()).filter(each -> 
                          userNames.indexOf(each) == -1)
                         .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't.

This is classical "input/output" testing only. You simply want to create an **input** list that contains specific objects, so that you can **predict** what should come out of that operation.

In other words, your test should in essence look like:

```
assertThat(someMethodDoingTheStreamOperation(yourInputList), is(expectedResult));
```

Mocking *containers*, such as List or Map is (almost always) wrong.

If you still insist on doing it, you could be using Mockito and its [deep stubs](https://dzone.com/articles/mockito-returnsdeepstubs-jaxb) support.

But again: that means that you start putting **implementation details** of your solution *into* your test code. This means that your test code is nothing but a "copy" of your production code. The second you change your production code, your unit test might break. So even simple refactoring might become a problem.

You always prefer to have tests that do **not** rely on mocking. And when talking about lists, then hey: fill a list with prepared input, instead of mocking the list.